# iPad UIButtons responding to external keyboard input

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, keyboard

I'm writing an app based around a calculator-like UI.  On an iPad, I'd like the number UIButtons on my calculator UI to respond to the numbers on the external keyboard.  I have no text input anywhere in the app, and I'd never want an on-screen keyboard to appear.  How do I get my UIButtons to respond to specific key presses as if they'd been touched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say create a hidden UITextField with the delegate set, make it become the first responder upon viewDidLoad. The keyboard won't appear when a bluetooth keyboard is connected as far as I know, then just check what characters are typed in the shouldChangecharactersInRange and activate the right buttons accordingly.

EDIT: a quick example I just made, https://github.com/benjaminq42/buttonTest , if you wish to have a highlight animation of some sorts you need to create a custom UIButton class. You can use 'setHighlighted' but that 'sticks'.

Comment: I think this is as close as you can get given the current API so I gave you the check... thanks.